How can I except "Event loop is closed" error?
I am using python for Binance future transactions.
The problem is that the program keeps stopping running with an error message "Event loop is closed."
I have tried different solutions which google and chat-gpt suggested, but the program still stops running.
Below are my codes.
async def main():
    try:
        while True:
            await function_1()
            await function_2()
            await function_3()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if str(e) == "Event loop is closed":
            first try
            asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
            asyncio.get_event_loop()
            asyncio.run(main())
          
            second try
            asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
            asyncio.run(main())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())



To solve the problem, should I offer full codes of function 1,2 and 3? They all draw realtime data from binance url.
